# Why does the same font have varying heights/baseline in the different devices?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been testing the same font (Big John is the name of the font) in different devices. The height or baseline of the font isn't consistent across devices.

Here are the pictures:

**Windows Chrome** :

[image: Windows Chrome]

**Android Chrome** :

[image: Android Chrome]

**macOS Chrome** :

[image]

**CSS for the button** :

```
.btn-grey{
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #CBCBCB;
}

.btn-content{
 background: blue;
}
```

**HTML for the button** :

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-grey">
   <div className={"btn-content"}>VISIT THE WEBSITE</div>
</button>
```

Comment: hey @Potayto, set `line-height:30px` in `.btn-grey`. may be this is the issue of line-height.

Comment: Make sure that the zoom is equal in all browsers that test code

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting either line-height or vertical-alignment properties for that element, so each browser falls back to it's own default styles. And of course, different browsers have different default styles.

The solution is to explicitly set the styles you want, e.g. by adding the following to your declaration:

```
btn-grey {
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Just an FYI, but className is not a valid html attribute, it should be just `class=`

Comment: Oh, about the className, I'm using React thats why its like that.

Anyway, I tried putting a line-height, but I haven't tried using the middle vertical-align.